# PHP simplexml_load_file with special chars in URL

Tags: php, url, character-encoding

I'm attempting to retrieve a local weather forecast, based on the IP of the user.

I'm using geoplugin.net to get the user location and feed the city and country name to the Google Weather API.

```
//Get user IP
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$geolocation = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip));
$geo_city = $geolocation['geoplugin_city'];
$geo_country = $geolocation['geoplugin_countryName'];

$file = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=".$geo_city.",".$geo_country;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

//Echo content of retrieved XML for debugging purposes
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```

It works well for most cases, but when I try it on my own IP, I get Søborg, Denmark (which is not 100% accurate, but close enough) and that gives me an almost empty response from the weather API.

The main suspect in the case, is the dastardly "ø"-character.

The XML that I want can be seen here: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=S%C3%B8borg,Denmark

The XML that I'm getting can be seen here: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=S

When I type this URL into the browser it works fine:

```
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Søborg,Denmark
```

When I use this version it works as well (in the browser):

```
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=S%C3%B8borg,Denmark
```

but this version returns the forecast for Borg,Syddanmark:

```
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=S%26oslash%3Bborg,Denmark
```

None of the above returns the desired result, when fed to the simplexml_load_file().

As stated, I suspect that it is a character set issue, but I can't figure out what to do about it.

What is the correct way to solve it?

I know that I can use latitude and longtitude as parameters for Google Weather API instead, but that's just circumventing the problem, not solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you URL-decode `S%26oslash%3Bborg` you'll see that this string corresponds to `S&oslash;borg` which gives us `Søborg` after we decode HTML entities like so:

```php
$city = 'S%26oslash%3Bborg,Denmark';
echo $city = rawurldecode($city);
//prints S&oslash;borg,Denmark

echo $city = html_entity_decode($city, 0, 'UTF-8');
//prints Søborg,Denmark

echo $city = rawurlencode($city);
//prints S%C3%B8borg%2CDenmark
```

And then:

```php
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather='.$city);
$xml = mb_convert_encoding($xml, 'UTF-8');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->weather->forecast_information->city['data'];
```

Outputs expected:

```php
Søborg, Capital Region of Denmark
```

Comment: Excellent!
Can you also tell me what the right way is, to turn "ø" in into %C3%B8? Is there a built in function?

Comment: Indeed it does, but the the string I get from the geoplugin.net xml, seems (according to `mb_detect_encoding()`) to be in ASCII, so when I `rawurlencode()` it, I get `S%26oslash%3Bborg`returned.
I've searched for [a way to convert ASCII to UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983989/convert-ascii-to-utf-8-encoding) and learned that ASCII in fact is a subset of UTF-8. I've tried `$string = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $geo_city);
 echo mb_detect_encoding($string);` as suggested in the link and it still returns ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed sound like a character set issue.  Have you tried converting the URL to another encoding, e.g. using [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), before passing the result into `simplexml_load_file()`?

Comment: Not quite sure what I'm converting to and from.
I've tried both `iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $file)` and the other way around with no success.
`utf8_encode($file)` yields no result either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$file = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" . $geo_city . "," . $geo_country;
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($xml); echo "</pre>";
```

It's taken from this maybe similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136549/949476

Comment: The response is still empty, like it would be if the service was called with this url: [http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=s](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=s).

Comment: So if you just run this code `$data = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Søborg,Denmark");` response is empty as well?

Comment: Yes, empty in the same sense as above.
I do get _some_ xml back, but there's no forecast data in it.